# Switching Azure AD Tenants in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

Is it possible to manually map all users when switching the Azure Active Directory connection for Azure DevOps?

The directory that we're switching to has guest accounts for the source UPN set up for 95% of the users in ADO, so they're automatically mapped. Rather than that happening, we'd like to map each source user to their new UPN in the destination domain.

**What's happening**

```
| Source UPN | Source Type |      | Destination UPN | Destination Type |
| ---------- | ----------- | ---- | --------------- | ---------------- |
| user@a.com | Member      | \    | user@b.com      | Member           |
|            |             |   -> | user@a.com      | Guest            |
```

**What we want to happen**

```
| Source UPN | Source Type |      | Destination UPN | Destination Type |
| ---------- | ----------- | ---- | --------------- | ---------------- |
| user@a.com | Member      | ---> | user@b.com      | Member           |
|            |             |      | user@a.com      | Guest            |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to manually map all users when switching the Azure Active Directory connection for Azure DevOps?

I am afraid there is no such way to manually map **all** users when switching the AAD connection for Azure DevOps. Automatically map behavior is **by designed**, in order to provide us with convenience when switching AAD.

If we want to manually map the users, we need to delete those users from target AAD before switching AAD. In this case, when we switch AAD, Azure Devops says "X member(s) of the `xxx` organization can't sign in because they're not in the `XX` AAD. Delete any unwanted users in Organization settings, and then Resolve for remaining members.". Hit the resolve button a page shows up with the Users, then we can match them manually.

Comment: Thanks for the information. That was what I figured the answer would be, so it's good to see some validation.